# Idiomatic way to return error/success from async function / go routine

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I'm just looking into go routines and channels and have a question about returning errors:

Where I have result or error I do the following:

```
func Do() (int,error)
```

becomes

```
func DoAsync() (<-chan int, <-chan error)
```

where the function writes the result or error to the correct channel and the caller selects on both channels

However, I'm not sure how to handle the case where the result is simply success or failure

```
func Do() error
```

I would normally return error or nil for success

```
func DoAsync() <-chan error
```

I can follow the same idiom and write error or nil to the channel but this seems clunky - In the first case, I would only write result OR error (not result and nil to error channel)
For success I could simply close the channel with no error but then I'm stuck as to how to read this.  I can read the error or for an error in the channel (ie closed) but this seems even more clunky

What is the best, idiomatic way, to achieve this?

I have googled many examples but they all seem to focus on either result channel only or result/error channels (or result and error sharing a channel with a struct)

Comment: There's no single answer to this. It's a matter of your goals. What do you want to do with these errors? Log them? Abort operation and return them? Something else?

Comment: I'm working on a library so I can only try to anticipate what the caller would want to do.
I anticipate they will log the error and then retry if the error indicates a transient problem or abort if not (depending on how important this task is)
- My current api sends a notification message via kafka so is probably not a fatal failure, In the C# library from which I'm porting, the return is simply waited on to prevent the application from terminating before the threads have all finished

Comment: If you want to just report errors, then do so. This can be done via a channel, or a callback, for example.

Comment: I want to report error OR success (ie task has finished),  I can easily write the error to the channel but what about success (As stated in the question, in the synchronous version I would return nil to indicate no error)

Comment: Also note that when writing a library, it's better to write synchronous functions instead of asynchronous. In Go it's trivial to launch a function as a goroutine, so leave the option to the caller how he/she wishes to execute the function. That way you also don't have to bother how to handle results, it's up to your clients.

Comment: If you want to report error or success, then probably don't use async.  Wait until the job is complete, and report its final state.

Comment: @icza - I agree, but in this case, the underlying kafka library is asynchronous.

Comment: There is no "idiomatic" way for this. The idiomatic way is to avoid having to do it as icza explained. In case you have to do it: Do what fits your needs.

Comment: @RobRimmer: If you're wrapping an aysnc library, you have two choices: Copy the library's idioms, or make it sync, by waiting for the async operation to finish. The latter is usually more "Go idiomatic".

Comment: At my $dayjob, an idiomatic way would be to declare a helper `struct` type with two fields—one for "normal result" and another one containing `error`, and make the function return a channel of that type. The clients would be supposed to receive from that channel and then check that the `error` field is not `nil`, and only use another field if it isn't—basically the same logic one normally uses with Go functions which have multiple return values, one of which is an error. But I'm with the other guys in this set of comments: first check whether your clients will actualy benefit from async API.